# How can I set Opacity of WebView2 control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, webview

How can I set Opacity of WebView2 control in WPF
I need to change opacity of WebView2 from 0 to 1 by using Storyboard but when I am trying to set "Opacity =0" to WebView2 it doesn't get apply.
So is there any way I can dynamically set its opacity?

Answer (score 0):

WebView2 is not a native wpf control，it does not support transparency settings.

you can use **CEFSharp**,it provides the same feature of WebView2, and supports transparency settings.

```
NuGet\Install-Package CefSharp.Wpf -Version 108.4.130
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simply impossible. WebView2 is [`HwndHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.hwndhost?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). it means they are native win32 windows placed exactly in location of specified in your WPF. So It's not a WPF element you can manipulate.

Comment: Hi @DemiDev , can we show static image untll WebView2 loads?

Comment: It's not impossible but can be tricky. You can open popup on same position of your webview2

Comment: I am not able to set visibility control on webview2. Is it expected or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is expected. just open a popup on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to somehow hide the WebView for a while, you can use Visibility.

```xml
<wv2:WebView2 Visibility="Hidden" MinHeight="300" />
```

Above that control you can show a loading icon or something and animate it, not the WebView itself.

```xml
<Grid>
    <wv2:WebView2 Visibility="Hidden" Width="500" Height="500" />
    <custom:MyFancyLoadingControl Visibility="Visible" Width="500" Height="500" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this approach, even if i am hiding webview2 and making visible only when its ready to load but still it shows white background before loading and take few millisecs to render.